# BeautifulSoup as XML parser produces an unwanted html/body

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup, xml-parsing

When using BeautifulSoup for XML:

```
import bs4
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><mydocument><b></b></mydocument>', 'lxml')
# add or remove tags in soup
print(soup)
```

the output has an unnecessary `<html>` and `<body>`:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><html><body><mydocument><b></b></mydocument></body></html>
> ```

**How to avoid these HTML-specific elements and output an XML with BeautifulSoup?**

This is not a valid solution:

```
print(soup.find('mydocument'))
```

because it removes the `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`, which I want to keep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try one of these:

```
my_xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><mydocument><b></b></mydocument>'
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(my_xml, "xml")
```

or

```
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(my_xml, "lxml-xml")
```

in either case `print(soup)` should output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mydocument><b/></mydocument>
```